# git merge subfolder of branch

Tags: git

I'm pretty sure this situation is quite common, but I haven't found any information on how to deal with it in git.

---

## Here's what's happened so far:

Imagine the following folder structure in a git repo:

```
/server
/client
.gitignore
```

The repo contains both the server and client code of a Client-Server application.

This is the revision history of the `master` branch:

```
a01... (changes /server content)
b02... (changes /client content)
c03... (changes /server content)
d04... (changes /client content)
c05... (changes /server content)
d06... (changes /client content)
```

At this point, we pick the commit `b02` and create a new branch `server_v2` out of it. On that branch, we make two commits `e07..` and `e08..`. Here's the revision history of `server_v2`:

```
a01... (changes /server content)
b02... (changes /client content)  <---- here, master and server_v2 are forked
e07... (changes /server content)
e08... (changes /server content)
```

And here's the revision graph:

```
a01
b02
 * *
 *    *
 *       *
 *          *
c03            *
d04               *
c05                  *
d06 <-- master          *
                       e07
                       e08 <-- server_v2
```

Note that all commits affect only one of the subfolders, and the first character of the commit hash indicates which one:

```
a: commit on /server, before the fork
b: commit on /client, before the fork
c: commit on /server, only in master
d: commit on /client, only in master
e: commit on /server, only in server_v2
```

---

## Here's what we're trying to do:

Now we want to put version 2.0 of the server online. So we want `master` to contain the `e07` and `e08` commits instead of the `c03` and `c05` commits. This is what we want the branches to look like:

```
master:     a01, b02, d04, d06, e07, e08
server_v1:  a01, b02, c03, c05
```

In other words, `master` should contain the new server (`e07` and `e08`) as well as the changes on the client (`d04` and `d06`). `server_v1` should contain the old server (`c03` and `c05`).

### Option 1:

We could rename the branches:

```
master    --> server_v1
server_v2 --> master
```

Now `master` indeed contains the new server version.

**Problem:** We lose the `d04` and `d06` commits on `/client`.

### Option 2:

Merge `server_v2` into `master`. Now the revision graph looks like this:

```
a01
b02
 * *
 *    *
 *       *
 *          *
c03            *
d04               *
c05                  *
d06                     *
 *                     e07
 *                     e08 <-- server_v2
 *                   *
 *               *
 *           *
 *       *
 *   *
[merge] <-- master
```

**Problem:** This way, the `c03` and `c05` commits are part of `master`. We don't want the changes on the old server to be part of the new `master` branch.

**Is there a way to achieve this?**

Comment: If you want the changes of your branch in master, simply merge the branch. Replacing commits is usually not possible (nor desirable). If you really want to get rid of the changes from those server-related commits on master, revert them first before merging the branch. Best is probably to develop server and client in different repositories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git checkout master

git checkout -b server_v1 ## create server_v1 branch as off the current master

git checkout master
git revert c03  ##revert commits you don't need
git revert c05 

git merge server_v2 ##merge your server_v2 changes into master (you can also rebase server_v2 onto master and fast-forward master to server_v2 if you want linear history)
```

That's it.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using `git checkout b02 -- server` instead of the `git revert` commands. This reverted the `/server` directory to the `b02` commit.